# Zenity as a datetime picker

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, datetimepicker, zenity

I see that [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/) can pick calendar dates with the `--calendar` option.

Is there a way to get it to prompt for a time too? I've looked through the manual and it seems like it doesn't. And if that's the case, does anyone know of a simple utility which can graphically prompt a user for a date and time?